# Stripe Custom payment Flow returning Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, stripe-payments

I'm following this guide: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart (my code is 1-1 the HTML code found on this page.)
I keep getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')" after viewing the console on the page. I also do not see anything other than a "pay now" button inside a box. How can I fix this?

Comment: *"I also do not see anything"* ... Same here.

Comment: You need to provide way more information here. What is your code, are you printing/ logging things? Where are you specifically seeing the error?

Comment: usually happens when you use querySelector or getElementById before the element exists